# Conditional formatting in Excel based on formatted output in other table

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

Say,I have 2 tables...Tables are related...

```
 1  3  5  7
 8  8  9 10
11 12 13 14
```

&

```
2 3 5 5
1 1 1 1
3 4 4 4
```

I have highlighted top 5 values in first table using conditional formatting rules.Now I want to highlight cells in the second table based on first table...Assume 11 12 13 14 7 10 are highlighted in first table....I want to highlight cells in second table occupied same position as of in highlighted cells in first table..i.e. 3 4 4 4 5 1 should be highlighted...How can I do that

Comment: How the tables are related to each other? Why the top 5 are 6 numbers? Why the 7 is within top 5 of table 1?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Excel` functions `RANK` and/or `COUNTIF` to calculate a sequential ranking list column for the first table. The expression is explained [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/td0067.html).

For the second table, you can then use conditional formatting based on the computed rank.

Answer (score 0):

Might just be an elaboration of @Axel's answer and I agree the details of the question do not make sense but the position of a selection of top (or bottom) ranked cells in one array (say A1:D3) can be used to determine whether or not to format a cell in the corresponding position of another array (say H5:K7):

Select from H5 to K7, then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=RANK(A1,$A$1:$D$3,)<6
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select formatting, OK, OK.

Change the `6` to suit how many cells are to be formatted which for `<6` could be more than five if the value ranked fifth is duplicated.